# mv command says "No such file or directory"

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, rename

I am attempting to rename a directory on an external hard drive on Mac OS X. When I tried in the finder I got an error that says, "An unexpected error occurred (error code -43)." -- so I thought I may be able to do it from the Terminal.

I tried this `mv untitled\ folder/ RED` but it comes back and says `mv: rename untitled folder/ to RED: No such file or directory`

I see the directory in finder and when I perform a `ls` command.

I am not sure what else I can try. OS X doesn't seem to want to let me do anything with this directory.

Comment: Chances are there are some characters you don't see. Did you type the `untitled\ folder/` manually or did you let it autocomplete?

Comment: @slhck I let it auto complete.

Comment: Can you give us a `ls -l` on the directory? What filesystem does the drive have? Is it writable? Can you rename other directories? Have you tried reconnecting the drive or restarting the machine?

Comment: Try: mv "untitled folder" RED

Comment: In addition to @slhck's suggestions, have you checked the file system's consistency on that drive? Do you have permissions to rename it? Did you try it with `sudo`?

Comment: @slhck `ls -l`: drwxrwxrwx  1 jeremyhodges  staff  12288 Oct 15 17:42 untitled folder  -- yes, I can rename other directories, yes I have tried restarting the machine and disconnecting/reconnecting the drive.

Comment: @FreudianSlip Yes, I have tried that with the same result.

Comment: @RandolphWest Yes I have permissions, yes I have tried with sudo. Not sure what you mean by check the file system's consistency on that drive, could you clarify?

Comment: Disk Utility has a Verify option to test consistency.

Comment: @RandolphWest I did a disk repair and suddenly the directory I was attempting to rename was gone. Luckily that is ok, because ultimately I was going to trash it as it was temp data put there by another program, but wow, I sure was surprised to just find it gone.

Comment: I'm glad it's sorted out. This sort of thing happens more often than you think, and why I'm a huge proponent of backups.